# Recieved "Ability to down-vote" at 475 reputation AS WELL as at 125 rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications, privileges

This is the second time I have seen this notification, once at 125 and again at 475.

[image: Banner showing vote down privilege gained at 475 rep]

Comment: Happened to me too just now, guess it was globally reset indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think with the new roll out of the new privilege (Ability to protect questions), it might have reset the notifications.

Comment: What new privilege?

Comment: Ability to protect questions. I got a notification for it today.

Comment: Ah, got you now, I have just had the same thing on this site, "gained the privilege to vote up" just now, that makes sense, cheers!