# Did I lose the "vote down" privilege and then get it back?

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

I was browsing SO for about ten minutes, when I suddenly got that banner at the top of the page that said I earned the "vote down" privilege. Thing is, I had something like 1,490 reputation at the time. I kind of took it for granted that I could vote down.

Am I just not voting down *enough*? Is SO trying to tell me something?

Comment: Possibly the same issue as this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78803/recieved-ability-to-down-vote-at-475-reputation-as-well-as-at-125-rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain this ... sorry about it.

I refactored the privilege system this week and noticed that users were not getting notified for a couple of privs. I reset it across the network which caused a few people who never got the notification (non veteran users) to get the notifications.