# Erroneous "privilege gained - vote down" message

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did I lose the “vote down” privilege and then get it back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78859/did-i-lose-the-vote-down-privilege-and-then-get-it-back)

On Stack Overflow, I just clocked over 1640 reputation, and I've now received the notification "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – vote down." This has to be a bug -- I've had that privilege for months, and I do remember already receiving the notification.

Seems like a similar problem [occurred here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow), but that was resolved as a "one time" thing, so maybe this is different.